# Is there a way to stop Windows 8.1 from trapping my mouse cursor when moving between screens?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, mouse, charms-bar

I just upgraded to Windows 8.1, and immediately I notice that unless I deliberately wind up and "slam" my mouse cursor against the edges of my screens, it gets stuck on the last pixel before crossing. I'm guessing this was in response to people who had a hard time using the charms with a mouse in Windows 8.0. Dealing with Windows 8.0's single-pixel traps in the corners was annoying enough! I don't want to have a chug a five-hour energy every day just to use a multimonitor workstation.

Things like this seem to commonly have a setting somewhere, be it in the control panel, the registry, some group policy thing, or elsewhere. I'm at a loss so far. How can I stop windows from grabbing my cursor?